# CSS - My alert has opacity

Tags: html, css

I am creating an alert in CSS, though it has opacity (can see the background through it), even when I set the opacity to be opaque. In my code, there is an alert, though you can see some of the green through it. Is there a way to make the alert completely white? Thank you!

P.S: Run the snippet in full screen, it works better.

```css
.alertback {
 z-index: 500;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: black;
 opacity: .5;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
.alert {
 z-index: 1000;
 position: absolute;
 width: 500px;
 left: 31%;
 top: 30%;
}
.well {
 background-color: white;
 border: 2px solid lightgray;
 border-radius: 5px;
 padding: 20px;
}
body {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="alertback">
 <div class="well alert">
  <p>This is an alert</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Set the opacity of `alertback` to 1 from 0.5

Comment: +ManojKumar You mean from .5 to 0.5?

Comment: Yes, both are the same. You need to move the `alert` outside `alertback` for the opacity to not have any effect on it.

Comment: You can also make use of `background-color: rgba(r,g,b,o)` syntax where o will effect only the background color of the div and not the opacity pf the whole element.